# Java - How to get character to the left of caret point (JTextField)

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, point, caret

I want to get the character to the left of the insertion point in the JTextField.

I already have this: `final int pos = input.getCaretPosition();`

How do I get the character to the left and right of this `int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about `textField.getText().charAt(pos - 1)` ?